# Creating multiply effect in painting iPad app

Tags: ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to create a painting feature in an iPad app for iOS. I have managed to get the colour to appear through touch, but I would like to recreate the multiply functionality of photoshop so the underlying black and white image continues to show through the colour. I started doing it with opacity but going over the same spot will result in it eventually being removed. I am using cocos2d and this is the sample code.

```
in header
CCSprite *background;
CCRenderTexture *target;
CCSprite *brush;

in init method:
background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"background.png"];
background.position = ccp(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2);
[self addChild: background z:-1];
target = [[CCRenderTexture alloc] initWithWidth:self.size.width height:self.size.height pixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];
[target setPosition:ccp(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2)];
brush = [[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"brush_spot.png"] retain];
[brush setColor:ccRED];

in -(void) ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event method:
[target begin];
[brush setPosition:<CALCULATED POSITION>];
[brush visit];
[target end];
```

I have tried using different blend functions on the brush but nothing has managed to create the look I want. I did get the correct effect when adding a sprite directly on top of the background and setting its blend function to

```
[sprite setBlendFunc:(ccBlendFunc) { GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA }];
```

but when I try to use this blend function on the brush nothing appears on the screen.

Thanks
Iain

Answer (score 0):

The blend function blends whatever is on top with whatever is behind. When you render to a texture you blend with whatever the texture is blanked to.. Which I guess is something with alpha 0. So you should draw to the texture using opacity.

When you have filled the texture with color and attached it to a sprite, you can render it again and blend it with your background sprite. Then you can blend using multiply.

Comment: Hi Minthos, thanks for your reply. I have tried different options but I have not been able to get this to work. Can you provide some sample code for cocos2d to achieve this? If I cannot get this to work is there any way to stop the opacity from multiplying? So if I set the opacity to 100 then it will stay as that no matter how many times the user goes over it?